# Integration problem with powers of trig-expressions

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, hypergeometric-function

Is there any (elementary) way to evaluate the integral $$\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos x)^{a}(1-\cos x)^{1-a}dx $$ for any $a\in\ (0,1)\,\,\,\,?$

I tried many ways, but could not succeed. Any idea?

EDIT:
This is what I got from Mathematica. It looks bit complicated. 
[image]

Comment: Actually I found the answer using the Mathematica, but do not know how to obtain that answer without it.

Comment: This looks to be a monster. What kind of answer did you get ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I'm getting an answer involving hypergeometric functions.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I have edit the problem add a picture of what I got.

Comment: @isyoung: Waiting to see your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos x)^{a}(1-\cos x)^{1-a}dx = \int_0^1 \frac{x^a(1-x)^{1-a}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx = \int_0^1 x^a (1-x)^{1/2-a}(1+x)^{-1/2}dx$$

The following integral representation for ${_2}F_1$:
$${_2}F_1(\alpha,\beta;\gamma;z) = \frac{\Gamma(\gamma)}{\Gamma(\beta)\Gamma(\gamma-\beta)}\int_0^1 x^{\beta-1}(1-x)^{\gamma-\beta-1}(1-zx)^{-\alpha} dx$$ gives

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos x)^{a}(1-\cos x)^{1-a}dx = \frac{\Gamma(a+1)\Gamma(3/2-a)}{\Gamma(5/2)}{_2}F_1(\frac{1}{2},a+1;\frac{5}{2};-1)$$

Comment: Could you give details about the transformation in the first line?

Comment: @sirous Subsitute $x=\arccos u$, $dx =-du/\sqrt{1-u^2} $